# Converting a matrix to raw bytes in a specific format

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, mapreduce

I have the following matrix

```
B = [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

and would like to store the matrix as lines of the syntax `i j b_ij` where `i` and `j` are the matrix indices and `b_ij` is the value at that indexed position.

That is, the matrix above would look like:

```
0 0 1
0 1 2
1 0 3
1 1 4
```

Is there anyway to do this with a library in Python? Also, is this a common format for storing a matrix as raw bytes? I know it is easy enough to iterate over a matrix to store it in this fashion but that seems rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a library, but you can just use a list comprehension:

```
>>> B = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> matrix = [ [i, j, B[i][j]] for i in range(len(B)) for j in range(len(B[i])) ]
>>> print(matrix)
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 3], [1, 1, 4]]
```

You could also expand the `for` loop to do something similar, or nest comprehensions inside each other if your matrix `B` goes deeper than this.